# What are the applications of materials if their entropy increases with temperature?

Tags: temperature, entropy, material-science

***What could be the possible applications of the materials if their entropy increases with increasing temperature.***

Comment: What kind of "applications" did you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter has many useful properties irrespective of entropy: it bends spacetime efficiently due to its high mass-energy density, it can be converted into energy, it can retain structure, and it can perform many kinds of services - insulation, conduction, computation, and much else.

On a less abstract level: just because materials become more random and noisy as they are heated doesn't mean they lose their properties uselessly. For example, tantalum hafnium carbide has an extreme melting point of 4263K that is *increased* by entropy since melting would actually reduce the entropy somewhat (in this case the dislocations in the lattice has unusually high entropy compared to the melt). In magnetic alloys magnetization remains until the Curie temperature where it fairly suddenly disappears, something that has many technical uses. Also, many materials are useful as entropy sinks for other systems: their capacity to rapidly increase entropy with temperature means that they have a high heat capacity, making them useful in cooling and heat transport.